# How can I automate an Oracle-SQL-Developer task that involves running 934K queries using parameters given to me in an excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, automation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been given an excel file where data from previous queries has been stored.  Now each of those rows worth of data need two more columns from the database, so I'll need to use the data in each excel row as parameters for each query to add the addition info.  Also with 934k rows, I'll need to automate this process.  I'm not even sure really where to start so any help is much appreciated!

*****Updated

Thanks for the responses, here is more info

Data requests come in from different people for all sorts of different reasons, so I did not run this query originally.  I dont have the query that was run for this data either.

As for more detail to what I'm doing:

as an example, lets say someone requested data for people within the company and an example employee is in the data below.

(except its in an excel sheet and there are 934K of them)

{
 name: bill
 gender: male
 weight:200
 eye-color:blue
}

Some1 else is asking for this data but they want two more fields appended to it (Lets say height and hair-color).

I need to write a query for each person to get these two requested pieces of data.

I dont know why the data I was given was queried, I don't know what its for or what they were trying to do.  I just have that data within the excel sheet to use as parameters.

Hope this is more specific.

Comment: I'd write code to do it and if I ran into a problem, I would post the relevant section of the code here and ask for help fixing it.

Comment: I would load those rows into a table in your database, then rewrite whatever it is you need to use the data for to reference your table, rather than using the values as parameters on a row by row basis. It is pretty difficult to be more specific though when your question is so vague.

Comment: the data in Excel came from the database. Full stop. Go BACK to the database, run the query (or plsql) again and generate the missing data. And do you really want a 1M row XLSX at the end? For what - reporting? to feed into another system?

Comment: I updated the original question with more info, hope it clears up what I'm doing

Comment: I am with @GarethD and thatjeffsmith on this one. Load your spread sheet into a table in the database, then do your queries from there. From what you have written, I would load the data into a table as a row, then use regular expressions to parse out the elements into fields.

Comment: you say you don't know how the data was compiled, what queries were used. we're saying - go find that out. you'll be more successful at the end of the day and YOUR customers will be better served. what you've been asked to build is not....good.